# Não consigo ver o arquivo .htaccess e nem arquivos binários no ftp

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-aws, filezilla

utilizo uma instância ubuntu 16.04+apache+vsftpd na amazon ec2.

Não consigo ver o arquivo .htaccess via ftp, mas no vps ele está lá.

O que pode ser? Arquivos binários eu também não consigo ver via ftp, será queo problema é vsftpd na vps, ou pode ser no cliente ftp?

O que fazer?

Comment: Como você está acessando o servidor FTP? Alguns casos é necessário passar o parâmetro `-a`para listar todos os arquivos (include os ocultos). Ps.: Os arquivos ocultos no Linux, começam com ponto.

Comment: Ou você pode adicionar `force_dot_files=YES` na configuração do seu servidor FTP e reinicia-lo.

Comment: Acho que essa ultima dica resolveria...

Comment: Eu estou acessando normalmente, utilizo como cliente, o filezilla no windows. Configurado o protocolo como: FTP, tipo de logon normal, usuario e senha. Mas neste caso ele não consegue mostrar os ".arquivos", e tem mais, nesse caso eu não consigo trabalhar com arquivos binários, só aceita ascii, por isso acho que devem ser 2 problemas distintos.. Ai então eu mudo a configuração para o protocolo: SFTP com logon via Arquivo de chave, mas isto não é o ideal por que nesse caso estou utilizando o root lá do vps, funciona, mas não rola isso.